# How can you reduce the size of the letters after you increase them?for processing

Tags: processing

this program print text. this font size increase 5 to 250. when font size is 250, this font size decrease 250 to 5. then when font size is 5, this font size increase 5 to 250.
The font size varies by 5.
The code below is what I made.
However, I can't reduce the size of the letters after raising them.

```
PFont myFont;
int ts= 5;
int ts2 = 250;
float x, y;


void setup() {
 size(500, 500);
 x = width/2;
 y = height/2;
 myFont = loadFont("휴먼가는샘체-48.vlw");
 textFont(myFont);
 fill(255);
}

void draw() {
 background(180);
 textSize(ts);
 textAlign(CENTER);
 text("이재용", x, y);
 ts+=5;
 delay(100);
}
```

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i edited my question plz check my question again @Black0ut

Comment: More information about your environment would be helpful. I.e., what language is this? You mentioned Processing in the title, but it's helpful to mention it again more clearly in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to control the font size  increase/decrease you can add a step variable to the global state of the application and once the size reaches a boundary just invert the step direction, example:

```
PFont myFont;
int ts= 5;
int step = 5;
int ts2 = 250;
float x, y;

void setup() {
 size(500, 500);
 x = width/2;
 y = height/2;
 myFont = createFont("Georgia", 32);
 textFont(myFont);
 fill(255);
}

void draw() {
 background(180);
 textSize(ts);
 textAlign(CENTER);
 text("gf", x, y);

 if(ts>=250){
   step = -5;
 }else if(ts<=5){
   step = 5;
 }

 ts+=step;
 delay(100);
}
```